# Does even number of Kafka brokers affect ensemble operation and leader election

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

we are little confuse about if is valid or not to use kafka cluster with even numbers

the story begin when we build kafka cluster with 6 machines and trying to use the kafka Reassignment partitions tool , because non balance of kafka brokers

unfortunately ,  kafka Reassignment partitions tool not succeeded to Reassignment partitions

so we suspect about the even number of our kafka machines

so is it true or false ? , to use kafka even number?

Comment: Does this answer your questions ? 
https://users.kafka.apache.narkive.com/nzVhIOvb/having-4-node-kafka-cluster

Comment: NO , this isn't professional answer

Comment: Why not? Hans on that thread is a Confluent employee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, with the [official Apache Users email thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201703.mbox/%3CC5CBEA48-C7C4-4C8C-AC8A-B01F5C4F9079@confluent.io%3E)

No, Kafka clusters have no such restrictions as that of a Zookeeper **Quorum** (see definition of quroum) ; in order to elect a leader, "more than half must agree" on a value. That's not possible with an even number.

> kafka Reassignment partitions tool not succeeded

You'll need to be more specific. I assume the rest of the cluster works, so why should an even number be an issue?

Comment: so why should an even number be an issue? - because we susspect that Reassignment partitions and one of the reasons maybe is that we have even kafka number

Comment: Suspect it of what? Why limit your question to brokers? There could be even replicas, or even partition counts, or always an even number of topics to run that tool against... None of which reasons should throw any errors, so what is the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

Failure of reassignment is unlikely to be caused due to the number of brokers being 'even'.

It must have been caused due to follower brokers not being in sync with the leader, or due to a network issue, or due to the leader broker going offline at a critical time.

The Reassignment tool works well if the partitions are all in sync before running the tool.

The tool will usually fail if Partitions are out of sync or if 
leader is down an election for the leader is in progress while the tool is running.

As a best practice, it is recommended to make sure the following conditions are met before running the tool:

1. At least one partition is in sync with the leader
2. Leader is healthy and no election is happening.
3. Out-of-sync partitions are not nominated as targets for reassignment.